# How to fix System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. in .NET 5 Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Getting an exception while calling repository method to query database (_repository.QueryCard).
It is saying that it "cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this err
or is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your applicati
on. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should l
et the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'CardsContext'."

all services and repositories have scoped lifetime

Here is my code:

```
public async Task TokenizeAsync()
{
    bool hasMoreElements = true;

    try
    {
        while (hasMoreElements)
        {
            var cards = await _repository
                .QueryCard(x => x.Status == CardStatusEnum.TestTokenize)
                .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize)
                .OrderBy(o => o.CreatedTime)
                .ToListAsync();

            if (cards.Count == 0)
            {
                hasMoreElements = false;
                continue;
            }
            rest of the logic
        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message, "Error while tokenization of Cards");
    }
}
```

Here is repository:

```
public class CardsRepository : IDisposable, ICardsRepository
{
    private readonly CardsContext _context;

    public CardsRepository(CardsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Card> QueryCard(Expression<Func<Card, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _context.Cards.Where(predicate);
    }

        private bool _disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

}

Here is context code:

```
public class CardsContext : DbContext
{
    public CardsContext(DbContextOptions<CardsContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.HasDefaultSchema("cards");

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CardEntityConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CardToBusinessEntityConfiguration());
    }
    
    public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CardToBusiness> CardToBusinesses { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see with your code is disposing the DbContext from within the Repository dispose method. For injected DbContexts, don't do this as the DbContext should be scoped to the web request with the IoC container managing its lifetime scope. Think of code like this:

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    using (var someRepository = new FirstRepository(context)
    {
       do something...
    }
    using (var someOtherRepository = new SecondRepository(context)
    {
        // Do something, Whoops! Context is disposed?!
    }
}
```

The issue is that when your first repository Disposes, you are telling the DbContext to dispose. Your dispose method should only dispose of Disposable dependents that it was responsible for the scope of, essentially instances of the DbContext that it initiated, not instances that happened to be injected. Those lifetimes should be left to be managed by what instantiated them. So each and every repository or other class that injects a DbContext and uses this Dispose pattern, you need to ensure that injected dependencies like the DbContext are *not* disposed within their Dispose method.